# Why does this code doesn't work?

Tags: c

This is in C, I'm using Dev-C++(but saved in c extension), and compiled with the compilator from Dev-C++.No errors or warnings are shown in the compile log.This program is an "array", "for", "do-while" exercise.

Sorry for any phrase mistake, my native language isn't english,and this is my first question in this site...
If you need any further information just ask(but I may not answer quickly).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main(){
    int num[10];
    int cont=0;  
    for (cont=0;cont==9;cont++){
        num[cont]=(cont+1)*3;
        }
    printf("\nThis programs show the multiplication table of the number 3\n Digit the number you want \n To exit input -9... \n");
    do{
       cont=0;
       scanf("%d",&cont);
       if (cont>10 || cont<1){
            if(cont!= -9){
                printf("You digitted a not valid number");
            }
        }
        printf("The number 3 multiplied by %d is equal to: %d \n\n",cont,num[cont-1]);
    }while(cont!=(-9));
    getch();
}
```

ps:Please no too complex answers, I'm very,very novice.And again sorry for my language errors.

Comment: `for (cont=0;cont==9;cont++)` This is wrong. The middle condition should be true when you want the loop to keep going. Change it to `cont <= 9`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (cont=0;cont==9;cont++){
```

The second part of a for loop is the continuing condition, not the end condition. Basically, the loop continues while that second part is true.

So, since cont starts at 0, and it only continues when `cont == 9`... it never actually runs. Try doing `cont <= 9` instead and it will go while it is less than or equal to 9.

Comment: Thanks!! Sometimes the syntax is just too much to remember :p

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that your problem is in this line of code:

```
for (cont=0;cont==9;cont++){
```

The syntax for `for()` is: `for(starting_with; while_true; do_each_loop)`
So when you say `cont==9` that means the loop will run only if cont is equal to 9.  You probably want something like `cont <= 9`.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems

1. The `for` loop's test and limit are wrong.

   ```
   int num[10];
   for (cont=0; cont<10; cont++) {

   // or even better
   #define N 10
   int num[N];
   for (cont=0; cont<N; cont++) {
   ... 
     if (cont> N || cont<1){
   ```
2. Code accesses the the array with an invalid index, add `else`

   ```
   if (cont>10 || cont<1) {
     if(cont!= -9){
       printf("You digitted a not valid number");
     }
   }
   else { 
     printf("The number 3 multiplied by %d is equal to: %d \n\n",cont,num[cont-1]);
   }
   ```
3. Code should check the return value of `scanf()`.

   ```
   if (scanf("%d",&cont) != 1) break;
   ```
4. Minor: non portable `main()` signature

   ```
   // main(){
   int main(void) {
   ```